# Query Search Algorithm using priority array and ignoring conditions

Tags: sql, algorithm, performance, search, logic

I am facing this problem at my companies logistics:

Given array of mixed values

```
arr = [
    v1 => a, 
    v2 => b, 
    v3 => c, 
    v4 => d
]
```

ordered by priority ASC (v1 is more important than v2, ... etc)

I need to search values in a table t like this:

```
select * from t where 
    ... And
    t.v1 = a And
    t.v2 = b And
    t.v3 = c And
    t.v4 = d
```

The 3 dots in query are the fixed conditions

If I cant find any value from query, perform same query ignoring the least important value from array

```
select * from t where
    ... And
    t.v1 = a And
    t.v2 = b And
    t.v3 = c
```

Again if value was not found. perform a query ignoring the next least important value

```
select * from t where
    ... And
    t.v1 = a And
    t.v2 = b And
    t.v4 = d
```

The query can ignore all elements from array as last query

```
select * from t where ...
```

Repeat that until find at least 1 query result or all elements in array are nulled and no result were found. (return false)

I did my search algorithm using binary numbers to find the value which works like this

```
binaryValue = (2 ^ arr.lenght) - 1 //(In this case: 2^4-1 = 15)
```

transform binary 15 in array of boolean exploded = [1, 1, 1, 1] (15 in binary is 1111)

Than make the query considering position 0 of booleanArray exploded if true then Consider value in arr of mixed values and so on

loop from 15 to 0 (the 0 iteration is when the boolean array is [0,0,0,0] and ignores all cases
The sequence will be like this with this logic:

```
[a, b, c, d] // [1,1,1,1] = 15 (select * from t where ... and v1=a and v2=b and v3=c and v4=d)
[a, b, c] // [1,1,1,0] = 14 (select * from t where ... and v1=a and v2=b and v3=c)
[a, b, d] // [1,1,0,1] = 13 (select * from t where ... and v1=a and v2=b and v4=d)
...
[] // [0,0,0,0] = 0 (select * from t where ...)
```

The search algorithm works fine but I have a huge problem to performance.

The number of queries performed in this search is arr.length! (fatorial) So when the array is length 4, the worst case scenario performs 24 queries.
if the arr.length is 6 (what is the length I am dealing now in my code in production) the worst case performs 720 queries which is unacceptable.

I need a way to Improve this search. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not the proper way to encode arrays into SQL because it violates First Normal Form.  This is in part why you are having so much trouble with this, the data's not relational.  But that aside, what you want to do is to create a calculated column (in the table or in a view of the table) that returns an objective score that reflects that row's desirability and then select only those rows with the MAX score within some grouping.  I'm guessing that the problem here is that your scoring is based on parameter values, in which case just calculate the score dynamically in a subquery.

Comment: I agree with you about the proper way. Nobody took the time to analyse and MER the database here in the company. Besides that I will need to fix this (if possible) without changing data structure (Which was required at the task description).  You gave me a spark of an Idea about this desirability algorithm. Thanks for the reply if I got something I came back with my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up to the solution using the concept of row's desirability suggested by @RBarryYoung

Instead of performing multiple queries, I fetch all relevant rows into a datatable (1 query) and for each rows I applied a score based in desirability. (Code side)

```
        Dim dicFields As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From { _
            {"v1", a}, _
            {"v2", b}, _
            {"v3", c}, _
            {"v4", d}
        }

        Dim intScore As Integer = dicFields.Keys.Count

        For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dicFields
            lstRow _
                .Where(Function(p) p.Item(pair.Key) = pair.Value) _
                .ToList() _
                .ForEach(Sub(p) p.Item("__Score") += intScore)

            intScore -= 1
        Next

        return lstRow _
            .OrderByDescending(Function(p) p.Item("__Score")) _
            .FirstOrDefault()
```

It reduced the complexity of n! to just 1 query and n filters. System are up and running smoothly. Thanks for the help @RBarryYoung